# Displaying Data From Database With Vb.net with combobox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I face an error in my syntax which is indicating near the `AND` Operator

```vb
If ComboBox1.Text = "" And ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Fill In The Details")
Else
    Try
        con.Open()
        Select Case ComboBox1.Text
            Case "Students Info"
                Dim a = "SELECT * FROM studentdb1 WHERE class = " & ComboBox2.SelectedText & " AND WHERE date_registered BETWEEN " & date1.Text & " AND " & date2.Text & ""
                displayTable(a)
        End Select

        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End If
```

I created a class called `displayTable` to use command passed through the parameter to display into the datagridview

```vb
Public Sub displayTable(x As String)
    Dim command2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    command2 = con.CreateCommand
    command2.CommandText = x
    command2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command2)
    da.Fill(dt)
    datagrid1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: remove "WHERE" ( AND WHERE date_registered BETWEEN) followed by AND

Comment: As suggested, you only use the `WHERE` keyword once but I suspect that your dates are going to be wrong too. Here's a tip: if you have a syntax error in your SQL code, it pays to look at - and show us - your SQL code, rather than just the VB that constructs it. You really ought to be using parameters anyway, rendering issues like what you probably have there with your dates moot. You also should not be using the `SelectedText` property of a `ComboBox` either. Much wrongness there.

Comment: - ComboBox1.SelectedItem -> returns an Object, you may want to use ".ToString".
- Double Quotes " " -> won't suit a String Variable, instead, use single quote ' '
- Sql-Statement -> accepts one 'Where' only'.
- Date1, Date2 -> What are those controls ?
- What is your Database ?
- Select Case ComboBox1.Text -> Use ComboBox1.SelectedIndex, instead 'More reliable if you fill the ComboBox at Run-Time.'
- Con.Open -> Use 'Using ... End Using' method.

Comment: "I created a class called "displayTable"" I think you mean you created a method (a Sub procedure) called `displayTable` It would be unusaul to name a Sub the same as the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to divide the code into User Interface code that interacts with the controls on the form and data access code that interacts with the database.

The `Using...End Using` block takes care of closing and disposing the connection and command even if there is an error.

The use of `Parameters` protects your database from sql injection. I had to guess at the size of the class column. Check your database for the actual value.

`.ExecuteNonQuery` is for Insert, Update and Delete not Select. You can load a `DataTable` with a reader.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private Function GetStudentsInfo(clss As String, d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            command2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM studentdb1 WHERE class = @Class AND date_registered BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2;", con)
        With command2.Parameters
            .Add("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = clss
            .Add("@Date1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = d1
            .Add("@Date2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = d2
        End With
        con.Open()
        dt.Load(command2.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

In the UI

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Validate input
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" OrElse ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Fill In The Details")
        Return
    End If
    Dim FirstDate, SecondDate As Date
    If Not Date.TryParse(Date1.Text, FirstDate) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date.")
        Return
    End If
    If Not Date.TryParse(Date2.Text, SecondDate) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date.")
        Return
    End If
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        Select Case ComboBox1.Text
            Case "Students Info"
                dt = GetStudentsInfo(ComboBox2.Text, FirstDate, SecondDate)
            Case Else
                dt = Nothing
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        dt = Nothing
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: it worked when i removed the second 'where' in the sql statement

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentions in the comments by Vijay:

> remove "WHERE" ( AND WHERE date_registered BETWEEN) followed by AND

But I have some other things I would like to point out:

1. `command2.ExecuteNonQuery()` will give you only the count of affected rows. You don't need it.
2. Try to use `CommandParameters` (you proberly need to redesign your code)

```vb
    Dim sqlString = "SELECT * FROM studentdb1 WHERE class = @Class AND date_registered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate"
    Dim command2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    command2 = con.CreateCommand
    command2.CommandText = sqlString
    command2.Parameters.Add("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox2.SelectedText
    command2.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date1.Text
    command2.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date2.Text
```